# continuity of $\frac{x}{1-|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis

please how to prove that $\frac{x}{1-|x|}$ is continuous on )-1,1(

I started by let $\varepsilon >0$  and $x_0\in ]-1,1[$,

$$\left| \frac{x}{1-|x|}-\frac{x_0}{1-|x_0|}\right|=\dfrac{x-x| x_0| -x_0+x_0|x|} {(1-|x|)(1-|x_0|)}<\varepsilon$$
then

$$ |(x-x_0)+ ( x_0|x|-x|x_0|)|<\varepsilon $$

how to continue ?

Comment: You didn't fix the subtraction of the fractions though. It's incorrect. You're missing a $-x_0$ in the numerator. And it should be $+x_0\vert{x}\vert$ not $-x_0\vert{x}\vert$.

Comment: By $)-1,1($, I'm guessing you mean $(-1, 1)$, or equivalently, $]-1, 1[$? Basically, you're looking at $-1 < x_0 < 1$? I've never seen parentheses used in this way.

Comment: I made corrections

Comment: you don't have idea?

Answer (score 3):

Hints: $|x|x_0|-x_0|x|| \leq |x_0||x-x_0|+|x_0|||x_0|-|x|| \leq |x_0||x-x_0|+|x_0||x-x_0|<(\delta)(2|x_0|)$ if $|x-x_0| <\delta$. Also $1-|x| \geq 1-|x_0|-|x-x_0| >1-|x_0|-\delta$. Can you now complete the proof?

Please find more details in the comments below.

Comment: we must find delta !!!!

Comment: Yes. From what I have written it is enough to find $\delta$ such that $\frac {\delta+2\delta |x_0|} {(1-|x_0|) ((1-|x_0|-\delta)} <\epsilon$, I am leaving this part to you.

Comment: Show that $0<\delta < \frac {\epsilon(1-|x_)|^{2}} {2 (1+2|x_0|)}$ will do.

Comment: what is the  if  in the first line ? @kavi

Comment: i can't obtain the same inequality

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $)-1,1($ means $(-1,1)$ since it is the only case for which the function is continuous. In that case, first principles is rather redundant. Namely $g(x) = x$ is continuous on $h(x) = 1-|x|$ is continuous and non-zero on $(-1,1)$, hence $f(x) = g(x)/h(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: I know this I want to see how we apply the definition